# Should I be using SetParametersAsync() for all [Parameter] properties?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am now using `SetParametersAsync()` for a `[Parameter]` that is not set when `OnInitializedAsync()` is called. But that led to my thinking...

Even a property as simple as `Visible`, while usually set to `"true"` or `"false"` could sometimes be set based on a DB query and therefore get set after `OnInitializedAsync()` is called.

So... should I handle every `[Parameter]` only in `SetParametersAsync()` and not in `OnInitializedAsync()`

Or, should I handle them in `OnInitializedAsync()` if they're non-null and also watch for them being changed in `SetParametersAsync()`

And associated question. For each parameter I handle in `SetParametersAsync()`, do I need to keep a local copy of what it was last set to, to determine if the new value is a change? Or is there a way I can ask `ParameterView` if the value is changed? (I can't find anything in my searching.)

This is a difficult question (did it change) as in this case, it's a List and so getting a "new value where list.Count == prevList.Count does not mean that the list didn't change.

Comment: "could sometimes be ... set after OnInitializedAsync() is called" - but only from the parent component, right?  Because you should not change Parameter properties from inside a component.

Comment: @HH Correct. I have created a couple of child components for elements I need in several places. One is `<AddressForm>` which has all the address text boxes and the code behone calls Azure Maps for validation & location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the following rule of thumb:

#### `OnInitialized-`:

Here I will get things ready for the component, and very rarely do anything related to component parameters. Very often I will set internal or private parameters/fields for UI based logic or other defaults not set on the parameter/field. Things like rendering of a loading modal, `EditContext` etc. If I have a component that does not have parameters, I will add all starting logic here.

#### `OnParameterSet-`:

Here I will add all my component parameter logic and do hash checking to identify whether a parameter updated. Useful when working with your `List<T>` example and it's much cheaper storing a hash string instead of a whole list.

#### `OnAfterRender-`:

I usually reserve this for JavaScript. In my ~4 years of Blazor, I've only called JavaScript here.

## EDIT:

Apologies, I misread the initial question and confused `SetParametersAsync` with `OnParameterSet-`.

#### `SetParametersAsync`

I've never needed to use this in the early stages. If you need to use this, ask yourself why. Rather see how can you improve or change the component to remove this dependency. Though I would use this on components if they are rendered in the thousands or have a lot of parameters, but then again, why render one component a thousand times? A high parameter count usually tells me that my component needs to be split into multiple components.

On simple components (which I believe all components should be), the performance gain from using `SetParametersAsync` is not worth the time to code. On the other hand, if I want to squeeze out as much performance as I can (usually late in the project), I will start updating my components. But then again, you might save 100ms of rendering time on large pages.

Blazor is very powerful in this way. I see many component libraries creating Jack-of-all-trade components when you can use wrapper components that bring in functionality as it's required.

For example, if you have a data table, make your filters a wrapper since not all data tables require filters. This can count for many types of components and saves massively on complexity and performance.

Comment: I'd forgotten that GetHashCode() actually walks the list. And that answers the question of yes, I need to save off the previous value. I now need to go through all my code and move the `[Parameter]` based stuff to `SetParametersAsync()` - thanks

Comment: @DavidThielen - note Marius's comment on `OnAfterRender` backing up my answer to your earlier question.

Comment: @DavidThielen - Marius doesn't even  mention SetParametersAsync so how do you come to this conclusion?

Comment: @DavidThielen, keep in mind that `GetHashCode()` uses the in-memory hash code and does not hash the object. This could bring back false positives. What I was referring to is a hash string which you generate using something like `MD5.HashData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToHash)))`. Refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=net-7.0#:~:text=Do%20not%20test%20for%20equality%20of%20hash%20codes

Comment: What do you mean by `OnParameterSet` above if not `SetParameterAsync` (which is what I assumed, apparently incorrectly)?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Yep - I have already undone my two uses of `OnAfterRender` that were not JavaScript focused.

Comment: For my use case GetHashCode() should work 100% of the time to tell me if the collection has changed. But you're right, that approach can be iffy if it's built around objects being edited that use the default GetHashCode().

Answer (score 3):

Consider this code

```cs
<h3>TestComponent</h3>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2"> 
    <pre>State : @this.State</pre>
</div>
@code {
    [Parameter] public string? State { get; set; }

    public override async Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        // emulate doing something async to get something before assigning the parameters
        await Task.Delay(1);
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
        await base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }
}
```

Looks plausible, but it will generate an error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The ParameterView instance can no longer be read because it has expired. ParameterView can only be read synchronously and must not be stored for later use.
```

Why, because the Renderer has moved on and the `ParameterView` instance is potentially stale.  You have yielded back to the Renderer and all sorts of sync code may have run that changed data in the `ParameterView` instance.

Answer (score 2):

Your question brings up an interesting point in Component implementation.

If you are using local variables to track state then you should consider setting and tracking them in `SetParametersAsync` and dispensing with the automatic setting.

This MS article describes this strategy to optimize components - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/performance?view=aspnetcore-7.0#implement-setparametersasync-manually

The important point here is it may be more costly in  dev time to code this manually, but in execution time it's quicker and less expensive: the automated code uses reflection which isn't quick or cheap.  You only code it once, but is could get executed millions of times!

I also beg to differ with @HH on `SetParametersAsync() is pretty tricky to use`, but that's a personal opinion.  Once you know the pattern to use, I don't see an issue.

Comment: I called it 'tricky' because I once saw a guideline about not taking too much time in SetParamsAsync and I had indeed made a mess by doing some I/O there. But I can't find that text anymore, and just verified that it behaves as expected now. Outdated info, I do like avoiding the reflection.

Comment: @HH - that was the advice, you must run `parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);` in the first line.  In reality, that advice is still very valid.  If your code yields before you apply the parameter updates, some other process may update them.  I'm increasingly moving to manual setting to control render cascades and save CPU cycles.  You already know my views on `ComponentBase`.

Comment: You just said three things in that comment that I don't understand but think I should. Could you please expand that comment in your answer?

Comment: See second answer.  You need to realise that [most of] us who answer questions here were early adopters.  We have 3+ years of knowledge [and scars] of the framework.  We've written our own component libraries:  libraries didn't exist in the early days and as a consequence we don't use other people's libraries.  We've contributed code to the framework [NavigationLock and the page locking is a refactored version of my solution to the problem].  Our component knowledge is hard earned!  Having said that  [I can't speak for others] but I'm more than happy to share it.

Comment: See this repo for some of my knowledge - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Components/blob/master/Tutorials/Exploring-Components/Introduction.md